# Django returned JSON, how to parse JSON Objects in js

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am returning from my django code JSON and it looks like this:

my django code:

```
objs = AccessInfo.objects.filter(~Q(weblink=''))
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', objs), mimetype="application/json")
```

what I get in frontend is:

[image]

I want to be able to iterate over those JSON objects in frontend with javascript and show each `fields` value in some html.

If I `alert(data)`, I am getting `[ Object, Object ]`.

I tried `$.parseJSON(data)`, but i am getting:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

how can I do it?

**UPDATE**:

my js is receiving the data like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/get_book_access_downloads/',
   type: 'get',
   data: {bookid:bookid},
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){
   // to do
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is **already parsed**. You have a list of JavaScript objects, there is no need to parse it again.

You used jQuery to load the data, and jQuery *parses JSON responses for you* when you use `dataType: 'json'` on the `$.ajax()` call; had you omitted that argument, jQuery would have auto-detected JSON responses by their mime type anyway and decoded for you then too.

See the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `dataType` option:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).
>
> [...]
>
> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

You have a list of 2 results; each result is a JavaScript object with the keys `pk`, `model` and `fields`, and the `fields` value is another object with each of your model fields.

Comment: thanks. I updated my question, showed how js code gets the JSON objects. how can I access JSON Objects in js. like  ``obj.attribute`` ?

Comment: @doniyor: `obj.fields.attribute`, where `obj` is one of the objects in the `data` list.

Comment: but if I do ``console.log(data.pk);`` i am getting ``undefined`` :(

Comment: @doniyor: you have a **list**; Use `data[0].pk` or `data[1].pk`.

Comment: oh now working like in fairy tales :)) thanks man. i need to dedicate one full day to study serializing.